# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 give me HTTP 500 error

Tags: installation

Hi 
I want to install sharepoint 2010 foundation on my Windows 7 machine for testing and development purposes. For that, I followed the exact steps described in MSDN under the title “  Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008” 

 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

After that , I run SharePoint products configurations wizard to deploy the remaining operations. The wizard run smoothly without any problems and it gives me the message “ Configuration Successful”
However, when it redirects me to the home page from my SharePoint I got the HTTP 500 error ( the page can’t be displayed). I also tried SharePoint Central Administration but still I get the same error message.

Any help would be appreciated

UPDATE:

 
I found this message inside Windows Event Viewer 

 

An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+msbin1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: ' 
 
 
IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error

I didn't find any log file inside my SharePoint root folder and I changed the attributes in my web.config as stated below. In addition, I changed the default port for SharePoint from 32212 just to try if it's gonna work on another port but the problem still occurs

Comment: Try an IISRESET from a command prompt. It's the SharePoint equivalent of "have you turned it off and back on again?" :)

Comment: the Internet Service stopped & restated successfully which mean no problems at all with my IIS

Comment: Always worth a shot though. Also check in IIS to make sure all the App Pools are up and running.

Answer (score 4):

Three things you need to do when you get HTTP 500 errors:

1. Check the event viewer for any kind of errors related to SharePoint, IIS etc
2. Check the SharePoint trace/ULS logs for errors, exceptions etc (they are located in {SharePoint Root}\LOGS by default
3. Edit the web.config of the web application you are getting the error on and set CallStack="true", CustomErrors="Off" and debug="true"

When you have more information, please either update your post with more error details or how you solved the problem.

Comment: Well, I found this log message inside Windows Event Viewer

Answer (score 1):

I remember having a similar problem, try installing the following module: rewrite_2.0_rtw_x64.msi (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1B8C7BD8-8824-4408-B8FC-49DC7F951A00&amp%3Bdisplaylang=en)

(I had blogged about a similiar issue earlier at http://vasya10.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/sp-2007-to-sp-2010-migration-issue-1/)